# What is time complexity of stoi (string to integer) function in C++?

Tags: c++, string, time-complexity

implementation of Stoi function can be seen [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/)

what is time complexity of above mentioned stoi function?

Comment: Theoretically it is O(n) where n is the length of the string. However since integers are bounded in size (a 32-bit integer can be represented with at most 11 chars in base10 form) it is actually O(1).

Comment: thanks for answer but i didn't understand that bounded in size thing if possible can you please explain in a bit more detail ?

Thank you

Comment: A 32-bit integer is in range -2147483648 to 2147483647. And so a 32-bit integer has at most 11 chars. Thus given a string it is enough to check first 11 characters to verify whether it is a valid 32-bit integer or not. And so the complexity is O(1) - it doesn't depend on the size of the string.

Comment: As is common with geeksforgeeks, that page has it wrong - there's no implementation of that function there. That site is a waste of time and not worth what you're paying for it. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @freakish you can have 32 characters of base 2 string fit in a 32 bit integer

Comment: @Caleth sure, I only considered base10. Regardless the number of chars to be verified is always bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time complexity of `std::stoi` is unspecified. A conforming implementation can use any algorithm that eventually generates the correct result.

As a quality-of-implementation issue, it will probably do a linear scan through at most log<sub>base</sub>(`INT_MAX`) + 3 digits, which is bounded above by `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`. That's O(1), but there might be any amount of preceding whitespace, so it's probably O(`str.size()`)